# Error Creating Business Intelligence Center

Tags: performancepoint

I am receiving the following error when creating the Business Intelligence Center site collection.  From what I can tell the Performance Point feature is installed and activated so I am not sure why this error is showing. Thanks for the help.

```
Error 
Feature with Id '8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: bf1ccdbf-e271-4337-a801-f356cd89c08d 

Date and Time: 8/3/2011 6:33:06 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the SharePoint Enterprise Site Collection feature, which pulls in various other enterprise features when it is activated. Check that this feature is activated (you will of course need to have the Enterprise SKU).

Also you might want to check your upgrade status in Central Administration and if necessary run the Configuration Wizard again.